Number as subscript in "enumerate" keys
I have an environment \begin{enumerate}[label=(A\arabic*)] which produces (A1) and (A2):
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
  \item \label{main_assmpt1}
  abc
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(A\arabic*)]
    \item \label{main_assmpt1:1} xyz.
    \item \label{main_assmpt1:2} pqr.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

One of our assumptions is \ref{main_assmpt1:1}.

\end{document} 


I would like to have the number as subscript, i.e., something rendered like $\mathrm{A_1}$ and $\mathrm{A_2}$. Could you explain how to do so?

I'd define a new list.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}

\newlist{assumptions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[assumptions,1]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[assumptions,2]{label=(\Alph{assumptionsi}\textsubscript{\arabic*})}

\begin{document}

\begin{assumptions}
  \item \label{main_assmpt1}
  abc
  \begin{assumptions}
    \item \label{main_assmpt1:1} xyz.
    \item \label{main_assmpt1:2} pqr.
  \end{assumptions}
  \item
  def
  \begin{assumptions}
    \item uvw
    \item qrs
  \end{assumptions}
\end{assumptions}

One of our assumptions is \ref{main_assmpt1:1}.
It is part of \ref{main_assmpt1}

\end{document} 


